# How to get last list item in Rules?

Tags: 7, rules

I have a multi-value field. How can I get the value with highest delta value in Rules? The only idea I have is to create a custom component a loop through all list values in it. Then I could use a auxiliary variable and compare each item with it (so that variable will correspond to highest value). This seems to be rather slow. Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Or add a `php script` step to your form and simply use the Field API to extract the highest value of the `delta` as a `variable` to be used later in Rules execution.

Comment: Thanks! That's certainly possible. Another option would be creating computed field and store the value there.